# How to update the items of an ICollectionView? Getting "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. [...]"

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, icollectionview

So I have an ICollectionView that's set as ItemsSource of a custom control based on the ComboBox.

I can set it just fine but I can't update it with new items as I get this:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify
>   elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

when trying it via

```
viewModel.TheICollectionView = new CollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(viewModel.OriginalList));
```

which gets called by an EventHandler whenever OriginalList has changed.

The ItemsSource is set like this:

```
<controls:CustomComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheICollectionView}"/>
```

Then in the custom control I have the event handler `OnItemsSourceChanged` where I do:

```
TheComboBox.Items.Clear();
TheComboBox.ItemsSource = _itemsSource;
```

The error throws at `Items.Clear()`

The other answers on this error didn't help.

Comment: Show us how do you set the `ItemsSource` of your `ItemsControl`.

Comment: @dymanoid: Updated the question. It works just fine displaying the first read in.

Comment: How do you go from `viewModel.TheICollectionView` to `Path=LabelsList`? Maybe you should take a step back and take a more attentive look at your problem. Or do you expect us to fill in the blanks with whatever fantasy we fashion...? ;-)

Comment: Okay. All i can say is: Probably don't add items the way you did. Do it differently. For example, by adding items to viewModel.OriginalList instead of tinkering with the ComboBox directly. I am just guessing here, since your question doesn't say anything about how exactly you/your code tries to "update *it* with new items"... (although my guess is strongly supported by the particular wording of the error message)

Comment: @elgonzo: but it does: I try to update TheICollectionView by the code after "when trying it via". I just updated the question as it wasn't clear that this is called in an eventhandler whenever OriginalList has changed.

Comment: Just to clarify: You do get the error when trying to assign a new collection view to `viewModel.TheICollectionView`? You are not trying to update the (existing) collection (or collection view) with new items, correct?

Comment: @elgonzo I simply want to change the items in the collectionview (and recreate the CollectionView _if_ necessary for that). It doesn't work when leaving out "new CollectionView(" either (getting the same error).

Comment: You need to debug your problem thoroughly. I have not enough information about your problem to help you any further. Pay attention to the error message. What is it telling about? It is referring to **ItemsSource**. That means the error message is related to ItemsSource. What is ItemsSource? It's a property of the ComboBox (or other ItemsControl). So your error is related to the ComboBox  (or other ItemsControl), not specifically to the assignment of a collection view to viewModel.TheICollectionView...

Comment: @elgonzo Okay, I'll inspect the customcontrol more closely. However this gets thrown at assignment and I don't see what the problem of ItemsSource might be. As said it works just fine with the first one. Note that I'm not implying that I know the cause of my problem in my question - I just want to fix it and am having trouble with that.

Comment: "*However this gets thrown at assignment*" yes, sure. Setting the property makes the binding update the ItemsSource property of the control, right? Perhaps start looking at what actually happens inside the custom control when its ItemsSource property is being changed. (Also make sure you don't have any other binding to viewModel.TheICollectionView and the ItemsSource property, just to make sure you are not getting confused or led down a wrong path when troubleshooting your problem...)

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks for your help so far. I updated the question with some more details which might be a bit confusing because I had to use two ItemsSource properties to actually set the customcontrol's ItemsSource. Note that it also doesn't work when putting "new ObservableCollection<Entry>(" before "_itemsSource". Still at it but haven't found a solution thus far...

Comment: Of course TheComboBox.Items.Clear() throws an error. Look again what the error message said. If you use an ItemsSource, you can't manipulate the ComboBox.Items directly like this. When using an ItemsSource, the control's internal item collection becomes read-only and fixed-size. (Hence why trying to clear the internal items list causes an error...). Solution to the problem: Simply don't do it. Since the your control is using an items source, that line would be useless anyway :-) Perhaps read up a little on how ItemsControls work with the internal Items collection and ItemsSources... ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo Sadly, it's not that easy: when leaving that out I get "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource". It also doesn't help to make that property a DependencyProperty and setting it as ItemsSource in the XAML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145728/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-myndstream).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the items to the `OriginalList` collection of the view model:

```
public ICollectionView TheICollectionView { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<int> OriginalList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();

public void Method()
{
    TheICollectionView = new CollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(OriginalList));
    ...
    OriginalList.Add(1);
}
```

You cannot *not* add new items to the `Items` collection of the ComboBox when you have set the `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: They are added to the OriginalList _before_ I intend to update TheICollectionView to match these items.     The assignment gets executed in an EventHandler whenever OriginalList has changed.

Comment: Try to update the ICollectionView is the same thing as updating the source collection. So how are you "updating"?

Comment: This is the high-level thing that I _actually_ want to do and might not equate to updating in any WPF-sense. But I'm not sure how it would be the same. I first update the OriginalList and then I'd like to update TheICollectionView which is set as ItemsSource of my CheckBox custom control.

Comment: This makes no sense as the ICollectionView is just a wrapper around the source collection. You cannot add something to only the view but not the source collection. Why are you event using an ICollectionView in the first place? You could just set the ItemsSource property to the OriginalList directly.

Comment: You didn't tell or demonstrated *how* you are actually trying to modify the collection...